# Why is a Boolean value stored as a byte inside of a computer when it only requires one bit

Tags: programming-languages, c++, boolean

I recently started learning to write code, and in my book I came across this question. "Why is a Boolean value stored as a byte inside of a computer when it only requires one bit?" can someone shed more light on this question?

Comment: This isn't strictly speaking true.  Some languages (like C/C++) provide ways of storing boolean values as single bits, if these bits are bundled in a single byte.  In other words, in C, you can store eight booleans in a byte.  But few ever use this since memory is cheap and processors manipulate data in 8/16/32/64 bit chunks.

Comment: [This answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220726/one-byte-bool-why) is what you should see! You'll get huge reference there... Cheers!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220726/one-byte-bool-why

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014161/in-c-how-much-space-does-a-bool-boolean-take-up-is-it-1-bit-1-byte-or-someth

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It has to do with what the CPU can easily address.  For example on an x86 processor there is an `eax` (32 bits), `ax` (16 bits) and a `ah` (8 bits) but no single bit register.  So in order for it to use a single bit the CPU will have to do a read/modify/write to change the value.  If it is stored as a byte a single read or write can be used to inspect/change the value.

Additionally one might wonder if it would be better to use a single bit vs a full byte, after all a byte will be wasting 7 bits.  Unless space is a constraint the one should go for the byte because, at least the x86 and I think others, there is usually an instructions to quickly set/clear a bool which is much quicker than the read/modify/write of a single bit.  From personal measurements I have seen the read/mod/write method be 5x slower than the single instruction method.

Comment: The only word you are missing is "Boundary Alignment".

Comment: On the other hand, I've seen a 2x speedup from using individual bits, presumably due to better cache usage with a smaller data set.

Answer (score 6):

[As @barrem23 explains](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/185107/8575), the data must be *addressable*, and the smallest boundary on conventional architectures is a byte.

But since this question is tagged as [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), it may be worth pointing out that `std::vector<bool>` is *specialized* to allow [individual elements to be stored as bits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool). This will save space by sacrificing some functionality (for example, `std::search` may not work).

Answer (score 0):

It will never be 1 bit, if you group 8 booleans in one byte, you still need 3 bits for each boolean for addressing (2^3 space), that is to know which bit inside the byte belongs to which boolean.

Also you might need one additional bit for nullability checking since you can't have a null bit, so you need one more bit for that, and you end up having 5 bits for each boolean rather than 1 byte (1 for value, 1 for null, and 3 for addressing), which is not that significant optimization.

Comment: I'm quite confused on this long sentence. These additional bits for adressing part is unclear to me. Could you give a more precise example, also related to C++ since it's one of the tags of the question? Also, in the context of this question, I don't think "nullability" has to be taken into account.

Comment: In normal scenario where a boolean memory reference points to the address of 1 byte in memory which contains either all zeros (for false) or all ones (for true), now to have 1 bit per boolean, you will point 8 booleans to the same byte, but you can't tell which bit inside this byte that gives you the value, so beside the normal memory reference, you will need a second reference that tells which bit inside the byte that has the value, this reference will be of size 3 bits to be able to address the 8 bits space.

Comment: ok, I get it now. Indeed.